# Unable to resume state of activity on clicking notification

Tags: android, android-intent

**Context:** There is a toggleButton which toggles between 'Record' and 'Stop'. When record is clicked, a notification is created to tell the user that there is a background service running, even if the user has hit the home button etc. and moved out of the app. On clicking the notification, the user should be able to come to the activity and 'Stop' the recording and save the file.

**The problem:** If i click record (and thus toggling the button), then hit the home button, and then click the notification, it comes to the activity, but the toggleButton is in 'Record' instead of 'Stop'. i.e. it has not retained the previous state. I presume this is because a new instance of the activity is created instead of reusing the existing one.

**The code:**

```
    public void showRecordingNotification(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Recording in progress!");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Go to the app to stop.");
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent appPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(appPendingIntent);
        Notification notification= mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

The android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="space.wavicle.sensorvector2d" >

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <service android:name=".DataLogger"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReplayActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_replay"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="space.wavicle.sensorvector2d.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**What I've tried:** Googling around and hunting around SO, i found many people having similar sounding problems, and all solutions seemed to revolve around flags of the intents, of which i tried all the combinations that made sense. I also have `android:launchMode="singleTask"` (also tried `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`) in the manifest. None of them seems to do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should ask yourself a different question in my opinion.

why does it matter for that button, if the activity is a new instance or not?

how exactly do you know your recording state? if you are saving the state in the activity, that means if the activity is somehow lost(crash) or killed, you lose your state. that's bad.

you say you have a service running in the background, I would let the service hold my state.

## EDIT :

as for the instance issue, first of all, here's a link to google documentation so you can read further regarding that topic:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManifestForTasks

in short, there are 4 launchModes states, standard, singleTop, singleTask, singleInstance.
you can read the differences in the docs.

The way I see it I would recommend you to go with the "singleTask" state.

basically, in singleTask, if you open that activity again thru a notification for example, it will resume the current activity that is already open, you can debug it and see that you won't enter the usual onCreate, you will go thru onResume (and OnNewIntent ofc..)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense - for the service to tell whether the record button should be on or off. I will try and implement that. However, shouldnt there be a way to get to a retained state of an app from clicking a notification? I'm sure i'm bound to need that sooner or later

Comment: I've been using singleTask itself all this while. But i have not overridden onNewIntent(). Could that be the issue? (I'm reading the guide you sent right now)

Comment: if you didn't override it then you're just not doing nothing there.

Comment: I see that onCreate gets called when launching from notification, even when the app is alive, even though its on singleTask. I've edited the question, to include my manifest. Can you spot anything there that i'm doing stupid?

Comment: try without this line:

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: I just flicked the CLEAR_TOP from someone else's SO solution. Removing out the notificationIntent.setFlags also didnt help. Nor did just removing the CLEAR_TOP flag.

Comment: I think i goofed up while testing after removing flags. Now, with "singleTask" on the android manifest and no flags on the pendingIntent, it is working as expected. On the guide you had linked to, i saw that, any flags on the pending intent will override the manifest's launchmode, if there is a conflict. That guide was very useful. Thanks for your help

Comment: I just saw that it was doing the recreation bit again with no code change on that end of code. And it turned out that the behavior went away after i restarted the phone!!! Hope this helps someone else who faced this same issue. But i'm still wondering if this will end up being a problem for the user.